# Insert Javascript into content page in ASP.NET without compiling it

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, contentplaceholder

I have an **ASP.NET Web Forms** application in **VB.NET**

In my application I use a `Master Page` and to insert **Javascript** for a specific page I use a `ContentPlaceHolder`.

I have a **Javascript** where I use code nuggets and I inserted in my page like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="javascript" runat="server">

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >

function showErrors() {
      var id = '<%=Request.QueryString("id") %>';
      <%if (Request.QueryString("errors") == "true")  {%>
          var errorCode = '<%=Request.QueryString["errorCode"] %>';
          var errorMessage = '<%=Request.QueryString["errorMessage"] %>';
<%} %>
    }
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

The problem is that when I build the solution, also the **Javascript** code gets compiled and of course syntax errors are found. For instance one of the build errors is related to the `if` statement that does not have a matching `End If` (as it is supposed to be in VB.NET)

How can I make the compiler understand that it has to skip the **Javascript**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write the `if` statement in `VB` language.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="javascript" runat="server">

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >

function showErrors() {
      var id = '<%=Request.QueryString("id") %>';
      <% If Request.QueryString("errors") = "true" Then  %>
          var errorCode = '<%=Request.QueryString["errorCode"] %>';
          var errorMessage = '<%=Request.QueryString["errorMessage"] %>';
      <% End If %>
    }
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works for the If statement however I still get errors on the var lines. Shall I use Dim instead?